# Ошибка кодировки при чтении файла .propeties после правки его из блокнота?

Tags: java, кодировка

Код пишется в idea. Кодировка файла UTF8 с галочкой native-to-ascii.
В файле есть русское слово "шара".
После сборки имеем вместо него

```
\u0448\u0430\u0440\u0430
```

Все работает, до момента замены этих символов вручную из блокнота.
Где то находил информацию что нужно использовать

```
properties.getProperty("db.host").getBytes("CP866")
```

Но не помогло

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите исключение полностью

Comment: @MikhailVaysman предыдущий вопрос стал не актуальным так как я просто указывал не верный путь.